# Post data send in python using socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I write a code who has to click a button on website, by sending a POST request. I use sockets to this. Here is my code:

```
import sys
import socket
import time
import socks

red = "\033[1;31m"
green = "\033[1;32m"
yellow = "\033[1;33m"
blue = "\033[1;34m"
defcol = "\033[0m"




s = socks.socksocket()
s.set_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "209.33.198.133", 9999)
ipaddr = socket.gethostbyname('mclista.pl')
#ipaddr = 'mclista.pl'
s.connect(("149.202.218.96", 80))


header = ("""
POST /json/daj_diax/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mclista.pl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://www.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 68
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.942145996.1539109230; _gid=GA1.2.1111512675.1541185659; csrf_mclista=65d10295bd238ea3c81f19b3e02d073c; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22d1e9deec40aa713329f98ddd11ce042f%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%225.184.63.6%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A78%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%3B+rv%3A63.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F63.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1541242717%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D913ae0005d8fb07d1b6dc486b7fc9297; _gat=1
""")

print(yellow + header)
request = header
s.sendall(request.encode('utf-8'))
response = s.recv(4096)
time.sleep(2)
print('\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' + blue + str(response) + '\n')
s.close()
```

My question is, why on send i getting it response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sat, 03 Nov 2018 11:20:02 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 226
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
```

Anyone know, how to fix it? Header is good, i copy it from firefox network tools. I need to send POST request, not GET. Code written in python 3.7
On i send it post from firefox, i getting normal response:

```
status: "ok"
```

Comment: You have newline at the top of your request. Try `header = ("""POST ...`

Comment: I try, doesn't work.

Comment: Headers is terminated by 2 newlines in HTTP. I suggest to you either reading HTTP protocol to send correct request, or to using `requests` python library to do the calls for you.

Answer (score 0):

Now i change a header to:

```
header = ("""POST /json/daj_diax/ HTTP/1.1 Host: www.mclista.pl User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01 Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Referer: http://www.mclista.pl/42204 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Content-Length: 68 Connection: keep-alive Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.942145996.1539109230; _gid=GA1.2.1111512675.1541185659; csrf_mclista=8cb69323a6f12ff338c06d4bea489c7f; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22b3df7ad8aef06a7428e497f90361eaef%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%225.184.63.6%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A78%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%3B+rv%3A63.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F63.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1541265085%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D14f5f5334fa1876215c215f1f81889c6; _gat=1""")
```

and to:

```
header = ("""POST /json/daj_diax/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mclista.pl
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.mclista.pl/42204
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Length: 68
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.942145996.1539109230; _gid=GA1.2.1111512675.1541185659; csrf_mclista=8cb69323a6f12ff338c06d4bea489c7f; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22b3df7ad8aef06a7428e497f90361eaef%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%225.184.63.6%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A78%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%3B+rv%3A63.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F63.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1541265085%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D14f5f5334fa1876215c215f1f81889c6; _gat=1""")
```

doesn't working now too. On first header the same response, on secound header no response, recive sending a empty byte (b'')

Comment: Now you send the whole header as a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use CRLF `\r\n`:

```py
header = ("POST /json/daj_diax/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
          "Host: www.mclista.pl\r\n"
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0\r\n"
          "Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01\r\n"
          "Accept-Language: pl,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\n"
          "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
          "Referer: http://www.mclista.pl/42204\r\n"
          "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
          "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest\r\n"
          "Content-Length: 68\r\n"
          "Connection: keep-alive\r\n"
          "Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.942145996.1539109230; _gid=GA1.2.1111512675.1541185659; csrf_mclista=8cb69323a6f12ff338c06d4bea489c7f; ci_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22b3df7ad8aef06a7428e497f90361eaef%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%225.184.63.6%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A78%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0+%28Windows+NT+10.0%3B+Win64%3B+x64%3B+rv%3A63.0%29+Gecko%2F20100101+Firefox%2F63.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1541265085%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D14f5f5334fa1876215c215f1f81889c6; _gat=1\r\n\r\n")
```

Comment: It is a single line with  `\r\n` inside. Did you try to print `header`?

Comment: I did try to print header. `( )` will basically join all strings inside it to a single line, so I use it to make it easier to look